# nth-child(4n) in jquery for old browsers

Tags: jquery, css, wordpress, html, css-selectors

This code works fine in all browsers, but in internet explorer and older browsers don't work. It's possible do it with jquery too for old browsers and internet explorer?

```
.post {position:relative;float:left;width:207px;height:300px;margin-right:24px}
.post:nth-child(4n) {margin-right:0px !important;}
```

Comment: He specified jquery in his question...

Comment: because he wants to use jQuery to implement the style in browsers that don't support the selector?

Comment: Are these "posts" being output to the page from the server? if so, it would be easier and lighter to simply output a class directly on the intended elements and use that class for the styling rather than using jQuery to do it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can. In jQuery, try

```
$(".post:nth-child(4n)").css('margin-right', '0px !important');
```